# How to load multiple images with parcel?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js, parceljs

I have a pixi.js app that depends on multiple images which are inside a folder and i want to use parcel bundler. I can import them one by one (`import logo from "./color/btc.png"` works as expected) but when i tried to import folder, parcel give this error.

```
  /Users/user1/Desktop/pixi001/src/app.js:2:20
    1 | import { Application, Container, Sprite } from "pixi.js";
  > 2 | import logos from "./color/*.png";
  >   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 | const app = new Application({
    4 |     width: window.innerWidth,

@parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file './color/*.png' in './src'.
 Did you mean './color/d.png'?
 Did you mean './color/r.png'?
```

Is there anyway to achieve this with parcel bundler?

This is the rest of the code.

```
import { Application, Container, Sprite } from "pixi.js";
import logos from "./color/*.png";
const app = new Application({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    resizeTo: window,
    backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
    resolution: 1,
    backgroundAlpha: 0
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
const container = new Container();
app.stage.addChild(container);
logos.forEach(logo => {
    const sprite = new Sprite.from(logo);
    sprite.x = Math.random() * innerWidth;
    sprite.y = Math.random() * innerHeight;
    container.addChild(sprite);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this working by using Parcel's [glob specifiers](https://parceljs.org/features/dependency-resolution/#glob-specifiers) feature. Here's what you need to do:

1. Add `@parcel/resolver-glob` to the `"resolvers"` pipeline of your `.parcelrc` file. If you don't have a `.parcelrc` file yet, create one at the root of your project that looks like this:

   ```
   {
     "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
     "resolvers": ["@parcel/resolver-glob", "..."]
   }
   ```

   If you restart parcel, it should automatically install the `@parcel/resolver-glob` package into your project, but in case that fails, you can always add it manually with `yarn add`/`npm install`/etc.
2. Import references to the files in your folder using this syntax:

   ```js
   import * as logos from "./colors/*.png";
   ```

   If the `colors` folder contains two files `a.png` and `b.png`, then the `logos` variable at runtime will be an object that looks like this:

   ```
   {
      a: "string url to a.png",
      b: "string url to b.png"
   }
   ```
3. Iterate over the values of the `logos` object, and do whatever you want with the image URLs, e.g.:

   ```js
   Object.values(logos).forEach((logoUrl) => {
     const sprite = new Sprite.from(logoUrl);
     // ...
   });
   ```